# Lost connection to MySQL server during query with python programm

Tags: python, mysql, ssh

I am trying to connect to a MySQL database using a python program with a SSH Tunnel.
I can connect to database using MySQL Workbench (Ubuntu App), with "Standard TCP/IP over SSH" option.
Workbench fields:

```
SSH Hostname: 192.168.88.80:22
SSH Username: ssh_name
SSH Password: xxx
MySQL Hostname 127.0.0.1
MySQL Server Port: 3306
Username: data_iser
Password: xxx
```

But when I run my python program it says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "mySQL.py", line 62, in <module>
    cursor.execute(query)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 166, in execute
    result = self._query(query)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 322, in _query
    conn.query(q)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 852, in query
    self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1053, in _read_query_result
    result.read()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1336, in read
    first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 983, in _read_packet
    packet_header = self._read_bytes(4)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1029, in _read_bytes
    CR.CR_SERVER_LOST, "Lost connection to MySQL server during query") pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')
```

My python code:

```
import pymysql
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder

with SSHTunnelForwarder(
         ('192.168.88.80',22),
         ssh_password="ssh_user",
         ssh_username="xxx",
         #ssh_pkey="/var/ssh/rsa_key",
         local_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 3306),
         remote_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 3306)) as server:

         connection = pymysql.connect(user='data_user',
                                 passwd='xxx',
                                 host='127.0.0.1',
                                 database='data_nme')

print "pre cursor"
cursor = connection.cursor()
print "pos cursor"
query = "SELECT * FROM data_name DESC LIMIT 1"

cursor.execute(query)
results = cursor.fetchall()
print results
```

Edit:
As you can see the first one is my python program, the database detects the query but do not send any data. The second is the query from the workbench:

[image]

Comment: Did your server crash during the query? Is it still available? What do you have in the logs?

Comment: My server did not crash I can query through Workbench. I dont have acess the database, but I think if I can connect with the workbench the problem is not from the database right?

Comment: See the comment on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39921388/ssh-tunnel-from-python-is-closing-automatically